# secondary fqdn for certificate authority

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, certificate-authority

I have a CA that is serving computer clients successfully and NPS (Etc.) is all fine. We are currently looking to move some services outside of the network perimeter and I would like to create a secondary cert for **users** rather than computers. One key shouldn't open all the doors, I know there's priv keys on personal devices for "special" staff etc.

fqdn ->
*.services.fqdn

Some questions:

- How do I create a subdomain for the same forest?
- The external radius server is not connected to our domain (ie uploaded the public cert and point it towards the crl)

  - Will the computer cert be able to authenticate against the subordinate cert?
- If anybody has done something like this before am I better off creating a *.client.fqdn and a *.services.fqdn
- Can I still have SCEP for the FQDN cert?

Thanks